# How to display records from MYSQL DB that are not empty?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in a database `table1` and `table2`

First of all I have used the `INNER JOIN` to obtain values from table1 and table2.

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name,
table2.location, table2.address
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id;
```

This query works just fine but the thing is that the address column in table2 `table2.address` contains empty/no values. Which I don't want to fetch. How to customize this query?

Furthermore,
I also want to filter a specific location `table2.location`.

For example, in simple words I want that when the results are fetched the location has to be "London" and addresses that are `non-empty`.

Comment: Add `WHERE table2.location = 'London' AND table2.address IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Add table2.address IS NOT NULL OR table2.address != ' ' (if any space) at ON clause

Comment: Please write the query for me. It is not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT table1.id, table1.name,
table2.location, table2.address
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
WHERE table2.address IS NOT NULL
    AND table2.location = 'London'
;
```

Comment: Please explain your code